# Wordpress Book Exchange Plugin Equivalent?

Tags: plugins, cms

I have a client which is in need of an entirely new website. One of the features of their existing website that they wish to keep is a student book exchange, where:

- students can sign-up and post any number books that they have to sell
- set a price for their own books
- take their books down from the website once their book as been sold
- other students can search for the book by title, author, or ISBN

They do not wish to have an online payment system, so a full-fledged online store isn't an ideal substitution. Here the site with the book exchange that I am mentioning:

> http://www2.gcc.edu/orgs/sga/bookx.php

Since I do not have the time to develop a content management system, or a plugin for an existing CMS, I am going to install Wordpress for them to use, largely because of its ease-of-use and flexibility.

Are there any Wordpress plugins that would serve as a good substitute for the existing book exchange, where students can sign up, but not have access to out control panels, just their books?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Custom Post Types (there are several plugins in the repo for that)
2. Custom Meta Boxes/Fields - a good library is the [»RW Meta Box«](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) set of classes
3. Extend the search - [there are several answers that show you how to do this in the [tag:search] archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search?sort=votes&pagesize=50).
4. Role Management: IMHO [»Members«](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) does the job best + it's well coded.
5. Reducing the interface - I got an [alpha stage plugin called »WP Strip Naked«](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/WP-Strip-Naked) for this. <sup>1)</sup>

<sup>1) If you want, you can just take the parts that you need. If you think it's a nice idea and maybe need it more often, just fork it and send a pull request. Happy to accept any cowork.</sup>